# Definition for the graph (cosine wave) when velocity is plotted against displacemnt

Tags: calculus

When $y = \sin x$ where $y$ is the displacement and $y'= \cos x$.
So, when plotted (velocity in $y$ axis and distance in $x$ axis), we get a cosine wave(right?).
So, when the velocity goes to negative in the graph, what does it really mean ?

Comment: Do you really want distance on the $x$ axis, or did you mean to plot time on the $x$ axis?

Comment: I meant distance.

Comment: What kind of motion are you trying to describe where displacement is the sine of distance?

Comment: I am totally stuck, actually. Is it possible for you to explain the trajectory of velocity vs distance in y'=cos x and what it means when its negative ignoring y=sin x?

Comment: I cannot explain something that you have not described. You have given an equation and called it "displacement" and you keep talking about distance in a way that makes no sense (at least in the context of any elementary exercise of sinusoidal motion). I suggest that you locate the place in your textbook or homework where it starts to talk about this particular problem, and then edit your question, copying _every word_ until somewhere past the point where you got into trouble. Then maybe someone can explain what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to say that $ x = \sin(t)$ where $x$ is displacement and $t$ is time? If so then we are dealing with simple harmonic motion. Let us assume that equilibrium is $0$ and that rightward motion is the positive direction and leftward motion is the negative direction.

We have velocity = y’ = $\cos(t)$ = $\cos(\arcsin(\sin(t)))$ for $ \frac{-\pi}{2} < t < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Let $v$ be velocity and $x$ be displacement If we substitute x = $\sin(t)$, then you get v = $\cos(\arcsin(x))$ = $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. If we plot velocity vs. displacement, you get a semicircle. By doing this, it does not seem like $v$ is defined when it is less than 0 for the x values in our interval. This is because during our interval, the particle is moving in the rightward direction, therefore having positive velocity.

In our velocity-displacement graph,  if velocity is negative and displacement is positive, it means that we are moving leftward with our position being rightward of equilibrium. We are moving towards equilibrium and increasing speed. If velocity is negative and displacement is negative, we are moving leftward with our position being leftward of equilibrium and we are slowing down.